# Custom Button in React Navigation Wix Bottom Tab

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm using React Navigation Wix for my App and I want to achieve something similar to the below design (Attached image).

Actually the problem with the wix is that we don't have the ability to customize too much things, we can config the text and the icon only.

Note that its hard for me to convert to the react navigation library right now.

[image]

Comment: Checkout this https://jaka-tertinek.medium.com/custom-bottom-tab-navigator-react-native-cda675172dac

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani this topic talks about react-navigation not Wix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there is no way to add a custom component as Bottom Tab Bar in "react-native-navigation" by Wix.

But you can implement the approach briefly described [here](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/6384)

1. disable bottom tabs showing
2. create your own tabs component
3. add it to every screen
4. get fun :-)

But you need to be aware that you will lose the default badge showing behavior (small red circles near the icon) provided by this lib.